# NameError on "recursive StructuredProperty" in GAE ndb

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I've modeled a data structure in GAE using ndb that is "recursive" in that I want it to store an instance of the same structured type within it. Conceptually,

```
class Person(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    friend = ndb.StructuredProperty(Person)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "C:\Users\Rusty\Documents\GitHub\AutoAddDrop\autoadddrop.py", line 2, in <module>
    import models
  File "C:\Users\Rusty\Documents\GitHub\AutoAddDrop\models.py", line 100, in <module>
    class Bid(ndb.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Rusty\Documents\GitHub\AutoAddDrop\models.py", line 123, in Bid
    outbid_by = ndb.StructuredProperty(Bid) #Winning Bid
NameError: name 'Bid' is not defined
```

Here's the class in `models.py`:

```
class Bid(ndb.Model):
    user_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    league_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    sport = ndb.StringProperty()
    bid_amount = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    status = ndb.StringProperty()
    target_player_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    target_player_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    target_player_team = ndb.StringProperty()
    target_player_position = ndb.StringProperty()
    add_player_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    add_player_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    add_player_team = ndb.StringProperty()
    add_player_position = ndb.StringProperty()
    drop_player_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    drop_player_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    drop_player_team = ndb.StringProperty()
    drop_player_position = ndb.StringProperty()
    bid_type = ndb.StringProperty()
    bid_direction = ndb.StringProperty()
    target_value = ndb.FloatProperty()
    transaction_timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    outbid_by = ndb.StructuredProperty(Bid) #Winning Bid
    outbid_by_key = ndb.KeyProperty(Bid)  #key of winning bid
    cbs_add_transaction = ndb.JsonProperty()
    transaction_reason = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs because when the class body executes the Bid class object has not yet been created.

You cannot have a model class contain a substructure of the same class -- it would result in infinite space.  A StructuredProperty *physically* includes the fields of another model in the current model.

So I recommend deleting the StructuredProperty line.

You will then get a similar error on the KeyProperty line, but for KeyProperty it can be fixed by using a string ('Bid') instead of a direct class reference (Bid).

You'll have to use outbyd_by_key.get() to access the bid's contents.

Comment: Thanks Guido - that's what I figured but thought it'd be preferably to completely denormalize if possible. Would it be possible / what are your thoughts about doing this via subclassing? ie. `class Bid(ndb.Model)` with all the meat of the class and then `class Bid2(Bid)` with just the  attribute `outbid_by = ndb.StructuredProperty(Bid)`

Comment: If you can get that to compile I don't see why it shouldn't work. :-)